# can you replace all errors on codeigniter with my own standard text

Tags: codeigniter

Might be a stupid question but hopefully not.

I'm due to launch my site in the next couple of days, and I am worried that there may be a couple bugs about, i've done the best to exterminate them but there may eventually be a couple that slip through the net, that i aint aware about.

I am wondering if it is possible, when an error does appear in codeigniter, instead of specifically saying what the error i can just set some text to be displayed like

"Error found, this has been sent to the website admin"

Comment: On my sites I make it so that the errors are invisible to the user, but they are emailed to me with other information about the request so I know what happened. If you take a look at how CodeIgniter handles errors, it should be easy to see where you can put in your own modifications. Hint: most of the files are in views/errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CodeIgniter 3, the error pages will be in `application/views/errors/`. There's different pages for database error, exception errors, php errors, and so on. You can remove the error message from these files and customize the page in any way you'd like. So for the `errors/html/error_db`, you'd just remove the line with `<?php echo $message; ?>`.

You can also disable displaying errors by setting the `ENVIRONMENT` constant to `production` and enable logging by changing the `log_threshold` in `application/config/config.php`.